# Howto: pass a username and password back into a webview securely

Tags: android, post, cookies, session, security

I have a user's name and password stored in their preferences.

How do I go about passing it back into the webview in a secure way?
I know if I do this it will work, but it just seems bad. There has to be a better way to post the variables.

webview.loadUrl("http://mysite.com?name="+username+"&password="+somepassword);

I've been looking for days and can't find anything, which make me think I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You should use HTTPS.

You can also send a salted hash of the password.  (Using a server-supplied expiring salt to prevent replay attacks)

Answer (score 0):

Create a WebViewClient which implements onReceivedHttpAuthRequest.
Connect this to your webview through method setWebViewClient .

For a working example see https://github.com/elsewhat/sapnoteviewer-android/blob/master/src/org/sapmentors/sapnoteviewer/SAPNoteView.java

Dagfinn